# Is there a way to completely disable DTR line of serial port in Windows?

Tags: windows, arduino, serial-port, uart

I'm working on Arduino Uno project which requires serial port comminication. On my Arduino board DTR pin of USB-UART chip is used to reboot MCU (It's connected to reset pin through capacitor) and that's what I dont't want it to do. Serial port driver on Windows changes DTR line state when the port is opened (resetting the board) and there is 3 options of `fDtrControl` in Win32 API:

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-dcb):

> `fDtrControl`
>
> The DTR (data-terminal-ready) flow control. This member can be one of
> the following values.
>
> | Value | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE 0x00 | Disables the DTR line when the device is opened and leaves it disabled. |
> | DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE 0x01 | Enables the DTR line when the device is opened and leaves it on. |
> | DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE 0x02 | Enables DTR handshaking. If handshaking is enabled, it is an error for the application to adjust the line by using the EscapeCommFunction function. |

I've tried all of them and using `DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE` partially helped, resulting in Adruino not rebooting every time the port is opened.

But there's still a problem - when the port gets opened first time after plugging in the cable, Arduino does reboot. Currently I'm looking for a way to change port configuration without opening it, therefore not making Arduino to reboot.

Comment: Isn't it better to have a hardware problem or a hardware solution?

Comment: @kunif I don't want to cut the DTR line beacause it's needed for avr programmer to flash the firmware

Comment: Therefore, it should not be completely programmable, but should be made possible by physical means such as jumper pins.

Comment: I may look into a proper answer to the question, but it may be worth pointing out that it is common to defeat DTR reset using a 10uF capacitor between RESET and GND. You can find instructions on how to do this on most tutorials involving the arduinoisp.ino sketch, because it is needed there to prevent avrdude from talking to the Arduino as opposed the arduinoisp.ino sketch. You _can_ also use a very strong pullup, about 50 ohms or 60 ohms between RESET and  5V. You do not need to physically alter the board.

Comment: I attempted to change the default `fDtrControl` by way of `SetDefaultCommConfig` prior to opening the port. The setting does not seem to take though, despite reporting success. Perhaps it will work for you though. Anyway, you don't strictly need to get this working in software for your particular scenario.

Comment: @timemage The same thing. Windows just ignores preceding SetDefaultCommConfig calls when it opens the port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in hardware, connecting pin 13 on Arduino to RESET and setting it HIGH (The lowest resistor I found was 220 ohms and Arduino was still rebooting with it attached as a pullup)

Thanks to @timemage.

Comment: Just a warning: I'm not sure how well this will be received as an answer, since it doesn't follow from the question and it's not really a programming answer.  Regarding directly wiring RESET to 5V, it's kind of a dangerous thing to do.  I expect it's a bit hard on the serial transceiver IC and it creates a real danger should you try to push your reset button while it is wired that way. Note four 220 ohm resistors in parallel on a breadboard can be used to make an effective 55 Ohm resistance, which is safer than direct connecting. The capacitor is preferred in any case.